# Get child page titles for all child pages within a child page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a menu structure like so:
Collections->
   ->Nike
       ->Football Boots

What I want is to display the page title of the second child page so that when I'm on the Football Boots page(the third child page) it always shows the page title of the second child page(Nike), I want to be able to have different collection pages but all have the same page title of 'Nike'

What i have so far is:`

```
<?php

    $current = $post->ID;
    $parent = $post->post_parent;
    $grandparent_get = get_post($parent);
    $grandparent = $grandparent_get->post_parent;
?>
    <?php if ($root_parent = 
    get_the_title($grandparent) !== $root_parent = get_the_title($current)) {echo get_the_title($grandparent); } else {echo get_the_title($parent); }?>
```

but this just gets the parent page title, I want it's child pages page title

Comment: Comment on what those functions are return... and why are you assigning variables in the if?

Comment: All that script returns is the parent page title of 'collections' whereas I want to return it's child page title of Nike

Comment: use SEO yoast plugin, This plugin give you option for title for each page.